# Creating new Web Application says "Master database does not exist"

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

When I am creating new Web Application in SharePoint 2010 from Central Admin, The Web Application is not creating and shows some error like

> Master Database does not exist

My system is Windows 7 64 bit and SQL Server 64 bit 2008, SharePoint Foundation 2010, Visual Studio 2010 64 bit, Everything installed successfully.

But now it shows an error when I am going to create a new Web Application.

Comment: Is this first web application you create after SP instalation? Or it was working before and it just got broken later? How was the SP installed? Standalone or script like installation? Try check if DB exists using SQL mgmt studio. If yes, there might be connection issue from SP, or the DB got corrupted. Do you have backup?

Comment: I am beginner, I have install for learning purpose no need back.., Firt i hve install SQl Server then Visual Studio and after Sharepoint Foundation 2010. After successfully install every thing i open SP and checked Centeral Admin is coming or not, But it was working when i am creating New Web Application at that time am getting error with some Corelation Id and some Master db is not connected like that.., Sp error..!! Please Give me some Idea.!!

Comment: If you have correlation ID, please go to your SP directory, C:\Program files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS here open the file with coresponding date/time and search for correlation id. It might give you a better idea what is going on. Please copy here the error message, or try to google it. Here is a tool to open the logs in more friendly UI: http://sharepointlogviewer.codeplex.com/

Comment: Hi luccio.., now another Problem with me.., When I am opening Sqlserver 2008 and Entering in SQL Authentication mode they are showing some Network Error it's not taking UserID and Pwd which i m giving correct one.., Now what i have to do..., Again need to uninstall and Install,  What to do Again i am confuse...

Comment: Could not connect to CHANDAN-PC\Sharepoint with user sa: Cannot connect to database master at SQL server at CHANDAN-PC\Sharepoint. The database might not exist, or the current user does not have permission to connect to it. 

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 

Correlation ID: 9df130e2-1a8f-40d3-9a0a-9ed5b1d16e31 

Date and Time: 5/24/2014 12:32:50 AM

Comment: Use SQL Manager to connect to SQL Server, then find the SP database and check Security->Users that there is the sa account.

Answer (score 0):

This is a SQL Server Error.

Verify that the Master database exists. And if not recover it from your backup.